# Send email to Person Account through flow

Tags: visual-workflow, email-template, email-alert

I am trying to **send an email to a person account through record triggered flow** but I get this **error** : "given sobject does not match type for alert: Account".

I have an email template and email alert on the Account.

I tried this workaround but still get the same error.
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000334427&type=1

any Idea?

Comment: Have you tested the workaround with newly created records or when the record is edited?

Comment: I simply manually set the email in the new field to test, but it does not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to use Email Alert on Contact and send the PersonAccount.ContactId

Answer (score 0):

When referencing the Account object, it was associated with contact object too. When you are trying to execute the email alert it will reference the Contact portion of the special object.

Answer (score 0):

I was also trying to send an email alert to the Person Account object using flow automation. I accomplished this by creating a flow on the Account object, adding my filters, then adding the email alert (which was based on the Contact object).

The steps to recreate this are:

1. Create your email template. In my case, I pulled in the Account fields for personalization
2. Create an email alert on the Contact Object (From Email Address Current User's email address and Recipients Email Field: Patient Email)
3. Create a flow on the Account Object
4. Add filters to the flow
5. Drag the "Action" element to the canvas
6. Search for your email alert (on the contact object)
7. Label the action whatever you'd like
8. for the "Set Input Values" field, enter {!$Record.PersonContactId}